# Where to publish proofs for, for example, the OEIS

Tags: publishing, oeis

TL; DR; Where can I publish proofs that are not groundbreaking nor profound?

I recently found an integer sequence in the [OEIS](http://oeis.org). Okay, the OEIS only contains integer sequences, so nothing new so far. However, the entry for this sequence mentioned an upper bound that I thought could be improved upon. The entry also mentioned a couple of properties for which I could find no proof in the referenced articles/literature.

The proofs for all of these properties, including the upper bound, are not trivial, but also not very difficult, I'd say first year undergrad.

I would like to expand the entry with the improved upper bound, but since I do not trust myself to be mistake-free and I do not expect others to trust me, I think the entry should contain references to proofs for every fact that it mentions, since it is very important these properties are correct.

My question is therefore: where can I publish/put/leave such proofs, in such a way that people who use the OEIS can read them as well (in order to verify it for themselves)? It is by no means groundbreaking work, nor very important, so I don't think any journal (or person reading a journal) would be interested in it, but as scientists and mathematicians, it is always important to give proofs for the claims we do. The only place that I could think of for such a publication is arXiv.org, but I am not sure whether that would be appopriate or not.

Comment: If the proof is short enough, you can post it here.  Use the tag "proof-verification".  If it's longer, my guess would be that the best thing is to find someone at a university to proof read it for you.

Comment: Well... I think it is important that such a proof can be linked to from the OEIS entry, in order for people who use the OEIS to be able to verify that it is indeed true.

Comment: So? if you post it here, say, link it to the OEIS entry.  Users here are well familiar with OEIS.  If people here confirm your argument, you could submit it to the managers of that site.

Comment: I don't know if there are guidelines for https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page but it might be a good way to put up a proof to have a link the OEIS can point to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are underestimating your contribution. If so, you could consider the electronic *Journal of Integer Sequences*: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/

Posting to arXiv and linking to that post from OEIS is a reasonable strategy, although it will not get you the proof check you want.

Comment: I did not know there was such a thing as the JIS! I could see if it is publishable there. If not, I might have it proofread by people I know and then publish it on arXiv. The most important thing for me is the possibility for others to verify how someone came to a conclusion, and whether that line of reasoning is valid or not.

Comment: I understand the hesitation to put it on the arXiv. There is some moderation at the arXiv and standards they have for content. For example, see https://arxiv.org/help/moderation and the guidelines they have there. I don't say this to discourage this approach. If the intent is to submit to JIS, I believe the criteria are satisfied.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few options. You could [submit](https://oeis.org/SubmitB.html) a file to be associated with the sequence. You could create a [OEIS Wiki](https://oeis.org/wiki/Main_Page) page for your proof. You could ask a question here about
the validity of your proof. There are other options with varying levels of practicality for
placing your proof on the WWW, for example, if you have your own website.
You can use a combination of these options over time. Also be aware of the
[Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/) of `archive.org` which keeps
the contents of websites even after they cease to exist.

Comment: Hm... The thing with my own website is that its persistence is very dependent on me. I.e. if something happens to me (or I get bored and decide to throw it away and create a new one), everything I published there will vanish.